# Symfony2 не работают куки на поддоменах

Tags: php, symfony2

Есть сайт с доступными доменами `site`, `admin.site`, `forum.site`
По умолчанию сессия работает только для домена `site`. У всех мауналах нужно просто добавить единственный параметр с `.` перед названием домена

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_domain: .site
```

Но, установка значений `.site` или даже `site` не дает залогиниться

Comment: Вроде бы есть проблемы куками на доменах первого уровня. Если у вас девелоперский домен буквально site, а не site.com.

Comment: @artoodetoo Домен `site`

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо комментарию @artoodetoo. Помогло изменение хоста на `site.local` и добавление в конфиг `cookie_domain: .site.local`